# Swift make UILabel text bold in between custom identifier

Tags: swift, string, fonts, uilabel, bold

I have a UILabel with a text of

`This is not bold, -bold- this is bold, -/bold- and this is another not bold, -bold- this is another bold -/bold-.`

now, I want to change the font of the text in between every `-bold-` and `-/bold-` in text to bold so it will become something like this

> This is not bold, **this is bold,** and this is another not bold, **this is another bold**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the strings within the delimiter.

```
let query = "This is not bold, -bold- this is bold, -/bold- and this is another not bold, -bold- this is another bold -/bold-"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "-bold- (.*?) -/bold-", options: [])
var results = [String]()
regex.enumerateMatches(in: query, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, query.utf16.count)) { result, flags, stop in

    if let r = result?.range(at: 1),
        let range = Range(r, in: query) {
        results.append(String(query[range]))
    }
}

print(results)
```

Next, Create a string extension method like below.

```
extension String {

    func attributedString(with style: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil,
                          and highlightedTextArray: [String],
                          with highlightedTextStyleArray: [[NSAttributedString.Key: Any]?]) -> NSAttributedString {

        let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self, attributes: style)
        if highlightedTextArray.count != highlightedTextStyleArray.count {
            return formattedString
        }

        for (highlightedText, highlightedTextStyle) in zip(highlightedTextArray, highlightedTextStyleArray) {
            let highlightedTextRange: NSRange = (self as NSString).range(of: highlightedText as String)
            formattedString.setAttributes(highlightedTextStyle, range: highlightedTextRange)
        }

        return formattedString
    }
}
```

**Method details:**

- first argument: Font style and other attributes to be applied for
  complete string.
- second argument: Array of strings for which new style to be applied.
- third argument: New Style (in this case, Bold) to be applied.
- returns resultant attributed string.

Finally, call the method as below.

```
let attributedText = query.attributedString(with: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .regular)],
                       and: results,
                       with: [[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .bold)]])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: your last parameter on query.attributedString is not an array and it gives me an error saying `Contextual type '[[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?]' cannot be used with dictionary literal` so I changed it to `with: [[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .bold)]]` after I do that I write `label.attributedText = attributedText` and the text on label was still the value of the `query` variable.

Comment: I corrected the last argument. Please check whether results array contains the list of strings that should be made bold.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NSMutableAttributedString` and set it to `UILabel`'s `attributedText` property.

```
let label = UILabel()
//Choose your bold font
let boldAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Non-bold text #1", attributes: nil))
mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Bold text #1", attributes: boldAttributes))
mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Non-bold text #2", attributes: nil))
mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Bold text #2", attributes: boldAttributes))
label.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
```

Comment: but that given string was changing time to time, it can be `some random -bold- string -/bold- and another -bold- randomised string -/bold-` so i can't put static strings in the function.

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation :**

Write an extension for `NSMutableAttributedString` and implement methods for bold and normal string arributes.

```
 extension NSMutableAttributedString {


    func bold(_ value:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]

        self.append(NSAttributedString(string: value, attributes:attributes))
        return self
    }

    func normal(_ value:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]

        self.append(NSAttributedString(string: value, attributes:attributes))
        return self
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
textLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString().normal("This is not bold, ").bold("this is bold, ").normal("and this is another not bold, ").bold("this is another bold.")
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working for me

```
titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11)
```